# How to seperate front end from backend with the same URL for express?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server, endpoint

I am currently running a express backend and angular front end. Whenever my front end makes a GET call using the service file, it hits the front end endpoint that serves front end files as opposed to the backend endpoint that makes the database request.
I have a server.js file that contains a get endpoint for serving the front end:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/frontend/dist/frontend'));
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/frontend/dist/frontend/index.html'));
});
```

and the backend endpoint i am trying to hit is

```
app.get('/api/product/:uid',....)
```

I have a heroku application. So when I make a callout with myapp.herokuapp.com/api/product/123, it hits the frontend as opposed to the actual api endpoint. Not sure how to structure my endpoints to serve the front end while also being able to recieve requests to the backend.

my current idea is to add /frontend/ or whatever before so that it will only serve front end components to /frontend/* , that way I can also make a /api/ call which would hit the backend GET endpoint. Is this the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: The wildcard you have on the route to return the Angular app would catch any requests and return that index.html file.

Comment: got it - so what is the convention to structure it? should i have all api calls start with /api and then have the route to return angular be /frontend

Comment: Yeah, that should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you folder structure:

```
/
 /public
  /frontend
    index.html
 /serverfolders
 server.js
```

frontend folder is the angular build output.

In server.js file, define all api routers first and after that add * route to send the index.html file.

```
// api endpoint definition
app.use('/api', api);


// Define Routes for client
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/index.html'));
});
```

In this context, if the URL resembles http://url/api/getdata, it will be directed to the API router. Conversely, if the URL differs from /api, the index.html file will be transmitted to the client.